# bin/rails server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

Ruby Version - ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

```
Error: 
Sorry, you can't use byebug without Readline. To solve this, you need to
rebuild Ruby with Readline support. If using Ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get
install libreadline-dev` and then reinstall your Ruby.
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/kg/Mysite/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously as though you have simply posted in a massive error message.

Comment: And a very self-explanatory error message I might add...

Answer (score 2):

Besides installing `libreadline-dev`, try to add `--with-readline-dir` option to the compilation of Ruby.

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=/usr/include/readline" rbenv install 2.3.1
```

Please double check that the readline directory exists beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a hurry,

Open your byebug's history.rb

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails/gems/byebug-9.0.5/lib/byebug/history.rb
```

and comment out the following line,

```
require 'readline'
```

But, It is recommended to use byebug for beginners to debug. But, there are alternatives like

```
pry, pry-byebug
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have no need for byebug. Thanks.

Comment: @BryceJohnson you can install the gem 'rb-readline' as an alternative to this and keep on using byebug.

Answer (score 0):

Like your error says, you need to install readline (libreadline-dev in Ubuntu) and then reinstall Ruby... Please do this.

Comment: I installed readline and then reinstalled ruby but it is giving the same error

Comment: Are you sure you're using MRI ruby 2.0.0 or above? It's a requirement for byebug

Comment: Actually I am beginner so I don't know what MRI is.
But when i did ruby -v
it gave
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Fedora, install readline-devel, then re-install ruby (for me it was with `ruby-installer`)

```
sudo dnf install readline-devel
ruby-install ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib 
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

works for me, what a magic!